# Pass value of ViewModel to a new Composable screen instance

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a composable function declared like this:

```
fun ScreenA(
    nav: NavController,
    type: SomeTypeObject,
) {
    val vm = getViewModel<SomeTypeObjectViewModel>()
    val state = rememberScaffoldState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LaunchedEffect(LocalContext.current) {
        when(type) {
             SomeTypeObject.TYPE1 ->{
                vm.updateState("1")
            }
             SomeTypeObject.TYPE2 -> {
               //do something else
        }
    }
}
```

SomeTypeObjectViewModel contains state variable of my ScreenA like this:

```
var remeberVal = mutableStateOf<SomeTypeObject?>(null)
```

Now at some point in another composable function i use my navigationGraph to open another instance of ScreenA, so SomeTypeObjectViewModel gets recreated and remeberVal restes istelf but i want keep and reuse it when new instance of ScreenA is made.

Passing remeberVal as argument using the navigationGraph is not an option since you can only pass Strings, ints or parcelable objects which is not my case, considering that remeberVal has MutableState<SomeTypeObject?> type.

At this point my question is:
Is there a way to pass remeberVal to the new instance of ScreenA or to avoid SomeTypeObjectViewModel being reinstantiated after when i re-route to ScreenA using my navigaion graph?

Thank you!

Edit:

my getViewModel() is a Koin function to injevt the ViewModel, the internal code is:

```
org.koin.androidx.compose ViewModelComposeExtKt.class @Composable
public inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> getViewModel(
    qualifier: Qualifier?,
    owner: ViewModelStoreOwner,
    scope: Scope,
    noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition? /* = (() → ParametersHolder)? */
): T
```

The navigation graph is made in something like this way:

```
fun MyNGraph(nav: NavHostController) {

 composable(
            route = Routes.CaseType1.route + "/{someParameters}/",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("someParameters") {},
            ),
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            val someParameters = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("someParameters")

                someParameters?.let { someParameters ->
                        ScreenA(
                            type = SomeTypeObject.TYPE1, // Notice here, where i change type but use the same screen
                        )
                    }
            }
        }

        composable(
            route = Routes.CaseType2.route + "/{someParameters}/",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("someParameters") {},
            ),
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            val someParameters = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("someParameters")

                someParameters?.let { someParameters ->
                        ScreenA(
                            type = SomeTypeObject.TYPE2, // Notice here
                        )
                    }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: If your `SomeTypeObjectViewModel` is scoped to the whole `Activity` and if you just navigate between composables inside the same `Activity`, then you can get the same instance of `SomeTypeObjectViewModel` if you retrieve it correctly - from the `ViewModelStoreOwner` - so show us what does your `getViewModel<>()` call do.
How are you doing the navigation? How does your backstack look like when you navigate to "a new instance of `ScreenA`" - are there two `ScreenA` on the navigation backstack or just one?

Comment: @Ma3x actually what I want to do is not calling some composable function inside ScreenA but the whole ScreenA. The idea is that when I call it using 2 different routes inside the NavGraph, I pass SomeObjectType as navArgument parameter so I can use it to do different actions using the same screen which is ScreenA, but indeed when I do this the ui gets recomposed and everything gets lost, including the ViewModel

Comment: Yes, I understood you correctly that you want to navigate to another "whole" `ScreenA`, that is why we need to know what is your `getViewModel<>()`(it is probably not calling `viewModel()` in it, thats why you don't get the same VM instance). We also need to see your navigation graph / NavHost composable, so that we can help you invoking your navigation logic correctly. Please answer the above questions and include the code snippets of those parts in your question if you want to get answers that will fit your code and your use case.

Comment: And the answer to this part "Is there a way to pass remeberVal to the new instance of ScreenA" is, yes, this is also a way, but you need to serialize (to a String or to a Parcel) what you have in `SomeTypeObject`, but we also don't know what your `SomeTypeObject` is, so nobody can answer that part either. You have to share more information.

Comment: @Ma3x actually I've already done this part, someTypeObject gets passed as a string. The problemi is i want to pass a MutableState<SomeTypeObject> as parameter to next route but I don't think this will work as a parcelable object...

Comment: No it wont, that's why I was talking about obtaining the same instance of the VM so that the same state (mutable state) could be accessed from both (all) routes, and I never suggested serializing the `MutableState`.

Comment: @Ma3x i updated the Question with the info you asked, actually i can't keep the same instance of my ViewModel since it gets reinstanciated every time you instance ScreenA.... That is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Koin for DI, so you can just add a dependency with a broader scope than your `SomeTypeObjectViewModel` that will hold the state you want to share between different screens/composables or between different VM instances. In that way your VMs have access to a shared state (a shared state holder is usually called a Repository).

```kotlin
class MySharedState {
    // this could also be a MutableState instead of MutableStateFlow
    // but then you are spreading the androidx.compose.runtime dependency
    // to a shared state that should not need to know about Compose
    val typeFlow = MutableStateFlow<SomeTypeObject?>(null)
}

class SomeTypeObjectViewModel(
    val sharedState: MySharedState
): ViewModel() {
    fun updateType(type: SomeTypeObject) {
        sharedState.typeFlow.value = type
    }

    fun updateState(value: String) {
        // your existing logic...

        // call updateType(...) when you want to update the type
    }

    // rest of your ViewModel code
}
```

Where you are configuring your Koin modules add (if you are using Koin 3.2+)

```
module {
    // a shared state scoped to the whole app lifecycle
    singleOf(::MySharedState) // <-- add this
    
    viewModelOf(::SomeTypeObjectViewModel) // <-- you probably already have this
}
```

If you are using Koin < 3.2

```kotlin
module {
    // a shared state scoped to the whole app lifecycle
    single { MySharedState() } // <-- add this
    
    viewModel { SomeTypeObjectViewModel(get()) } // <-- you probably already have this but add one more get()
}
```

If you also want to access the state in your composables, you can use [`Flow.collectAsState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow).collectAsState(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext))

```
fun ScreenA(
    nav: NavController,
    type: SomeTypeObject,
) {
    val vm = getViewModel<SomeTypeObjectViewModel>()
    val currentType by vm.sharedState.typeFlow.collectAsState()

    // ...
}
```

Comment: So let me see if I understood correctly: actually whatever i add inside sharedState.typeFlow.value, will survive even if SomeTypeObject ViewModel gets destroyed or I make a new instance? Plus in my composable with currentType I can always access the content of sharedState.typeFlow.value.

Comment: @androidexpert35 Correct, the MySharedState is scoped to the whole application scope so it will be in memory until the application is closed either by the user or (sometimes) by the system when it is in the background for longer. So only save state into it that needs to be shared across the application. If you would need to persist that state, you could always save it to some persistent storage (serialize it) and then restore it (deserialize it) when the application restarts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your super kind help! I really appreciated it! Have a nice day, greetings from Italy 

Comment: @androidexpert35 Good night then, neighbor, greetings from Slovenia 

Answer (score 0):

by scoping your ViewModel to navigation routes or the navigation graph you can retrieve the same instance of your ViewModel

visit https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation

```html
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = startRoute) {
        navigation(startDestination = innerStartRoute, route = "Parent") {
            // ...
            composable("exampleWithRoute") { backStackEntry ->
                val parentEntry = remember(backStackEntry) {
                    navController.getBackStackEntry("Parent")
                }
                val parentViewModel = hiltViewModel<ParentViewModel>(parentEntry)
                ExampleWithRouteScreen(parentViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```